# Real limit of IMPORTDATA seems lower than advertised (testing importdata with 1.5 mln cells)

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I try to import data from a .csv file located on my Google Drive. It's a csv file with ; as separators.
Filesize is about 4 MB. 46 columns and 8770 rows. It is possible to upload it manually to my spreadsheet but I need it to be connected via importdata or similar function and update.

When I try to import the file I get a message that contents of url exceeds maximum size.
Trimming it with nested array_constrain formula does not help.

My spreadsheet contains some sensitive data so I decided to make a dummy csv to illustrate the problem and see if you have the same:

Here is an array of random numbers 50 000 rows and 30 columns (1 500 000 cells). It is a 5,61 MB file.
Download link I use is:
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=19MBtGO-O7PV4NNojLAcxm-Pg8ZwjFXI8

File is located here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19MBtGO-O7PV4NNojLAcxm-Pg8ZwjFXI8/view?usp=sharing

When I try to refer to it using IMPORTDATA it tells it exceeds size, but it can be uploaded manually via menu.

[image]

You can play here with this file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16FprlLCST98CpB09CvtTK_CeSd76uUCsRRHWBF3bbMY/edit?usp=sharing

According to this discussion it should work anyway up to 2 000 000 cells:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10824/whats-the-biggest-csv-file-you-can-import-into-a-google-sheets

Comment: Yes I did (and mentioned in my post), but it does not help.

Comment: This seems to be a limit related the size that can be imported via `IMPORTDATA`. This doesn't seem to be documented. I'd suggest you to report this via `Help > Sheet help` on the Sheets editor. For a workaround, I think [Mario's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65918100) is appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If noone comes up with a google sheets formula solution, then you can simply use [Utilities.parseCsv(csv)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv):

```
function getBigCsv() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Arkusz2');
  const url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=19MBtGO-O7PV4NNojLAcxm-Pg8ZwjFXI8';
  const csv = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const data = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

and if you want the data to be updated, you can set up a time-trigger to refresh the data.